# How to extract the SQL Create statement from ignite

Tags: sql, ignite

Using Apache Ignite, is it possible to extract the `CREATE` statement used to create the table? You can do this in MySQL with the `SHOW CREATE TABLE x` command for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think dumping DML (database structure) is possible currently. Especially since CREATE TABLE is only one way of making tables in Ignite [out of three](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/durable-memory).

However, you can query tables, schemas and indexes via [JDBC](https://www.progress.com/blogs/jdbc-tutorial-extracting-database-metadata-via-jdbc-driver) metadata introspection feature.